# Returns a reference of an instance directly on a "None" match

Tags: rust

I'm new in Rust, I'm doing my first steps by resolving exercises on https://exercism.org/.

I'm creating a method that finds a `MatchDetails` in a vector, if it exists then returns the reference of this instance otherwise returns the reference of a new instance of `MatchDetails`.

It happens that `MatchDetails::with_team_name(team_name)` returns a new instance of `MatchDetails` based on a `team_name` and I want to use the reference returns from this `MatchDetails::with_team_name(team_name)`.

```
pub fn get_team(match_details: &Vec<MatchDetails>, team_name: String) -> &MatchDetails {
    let team = match_details.iter().find(|md| md.team_name == team_name);
    match team {
        Some(match_detail) => match_detail,
        None => MatchDetails::with_team_name(team_name),
    }
}
```

In the `None` match I would like to return something like `&MatchDetails::with_team_name(team_name)` but I get the following error:

`cannot return value referencing temporary value returns a value referencing data owned by the current function`

Comment: You can't return a reference to a local, so you'll need to re-think this. In Rust, it's often better to return `None` and let the caller do `.unwrap_or_else(|| MatchDetails::with_team_name(team_name))` where that's their problem.

Comment: Side note: [You should accept `&[MatchDetails]` instead of `&Vec<MatchDetails>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-string-vec-or-box-as-a-function)

Comment: Even better, accept `impl IntoIterator<Item=&'a MatchDetails>` (you will need to introduce `'a` as a generic argument.

Comment: @cdhowie Given that that's best, I sure wish there was a more concise way to specify that :D